# Alternative way to limit the number of inputs in command line

Tags: python, argv

I want to  write a code which limits the number of system arguments a user can enter using import sys/sys.argv

Lets say I want to limit the user to enter only 2 system arguments, no more or no less (3 if including the user program).

I have come up with a way using the len function, however I was wondering if there is another way to do this?

Here is what I came up with:

```
if len(sys.argv) < 3 or len(sys.argv) > 3:
    print "Please enter only two system arguments"
    sys.exit()
```

Again, is there anyway to do this without using the len function?

Thanks!

Comment: `len` is the standard way to get the length of a list. Why don't you want to use it? (You could use `if len(sys.argv)!=3` to save keystrokes.) What do you want to accomplish by seeking another way?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, you can do list unpacking with the exception handling, but why?

```
import sys
try:
    arg0, arg1, arg2 = sys.argv
except ValueError:
    # Your error handler
```